# Where to use Execute Scalar,Execute Reader and Data Set?

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net

I know I can read data from database using these three terms but can Any one please guide me properly when  to use `ExecuteScalar`, `ExecuteReader` and `DataSet`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When to use ExecuteScalar

[`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx): use it to execute any user defined function or the stored procedures, that usually has a scalar return value. i.e returns only one value. However, it can also be used with other queries or stored procedures, but in this case it returns *only* the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

> When to use ExecuteReader

[`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.71%29.aspx): use it for the usual queries that you pose to the database or with the stored procedure. The `CommendText` property is what determines whether it is a query or a stored procedure name. It sends the `CommandText` to the Connection and builds a `SqlDataReader` that returns a set.

[Data set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) is a different thing than the `ExecuteReader` and `ExecuteScalar` it represents an in-memory cache of data that are usually coming from the database.